# how to solve this into partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, partial-fractions

I'm having a bit of a hard time putting this into partial fractions:
$$\frac{10}{x^2+2x+1+\pi^2}.$$
I know that the roots of the denominator are $-1 \pm i\pi$, but I dont know how to proceed on puting this in partial fractions. Can anyone here help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get:

$\frac{10}{x^2-2x+1+\pi^2}=\frac{A}{x+(1-\pi i)}+\frac{B}{x+(1+\pi i)}=\frac{(A+B)x+A(1+\pi i)+B(1-\pi i)}{x^2-2x+1+\pi^2}$

So you have to solve the following system: $\left\{\begin{matrix}
A+B=0\\ 
A+B+(A-B)\pi i=10
\end{matrix}\right.$

Which is equivalent to: $\left\{\begin{matrix}
B=-A\\ 
(A-B)\pi i=10
\end{matrix}\right.$

The solution is: $\left\{\begin{matrix}
2A\pi i=10 \Rightarrow A=\frac{5}{\pi i}=-\frac{5 i}{\pi}\\ 
B=-A \Rightarrow B=\frac{5 i}{\pi}
\end{matrix}\right.$

So you end up with:  $\frac{10}{x^2-2x+1+\pi^2}=-\frac{\frac{5 i}{\pi}}{x+(1-\pi i)}+\frac{\frac{5 i}{\pi}}{x+(1+\pi i)}$

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{gather*}
I=\frac{10}{x^{2} +2x+1+\pi ^{2}} =\frac{10}{( x+1+i\pi )( x+1-i\pi )}\\
=\frac{10}{2i\pi }\frac{2i\pi }{( x+1+i\pi )( x+1-i\pi )}\\
=\frac{10}{2i\pi }\frac{( x+1+i\pi ) -( x+1-i\pi )}{( x+1+i\pi )( x+1-i\pi )}\\
=\frac{10}{2i\pi }\left(\frac{1}{( x+1-i\pi )} -\frac{1}{( x+1+i\pi )}\right)
\end{gather*}

Comment: :$(x-1)^2-i^2\pi^2\neq x^2+2x+1+\pi^2$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

Let the fraction be $$\frac{A}{x+1-i\pi}+\frac{B}{x+1+i\pi}.$$ Then $$A(x+1+i\pi) + B(x+1-i\pi) \equiv 10.$$  Compare the coefficient of $x$ on the LHS to see that $A = -B$.  Then $2Ai\pi = 10$, so that $A = \dfrac{5}{i\pi}.$  Hence $$\frac{10}{x^2+2x+1+\pi^2} \equiv \frac{5}{i\pi}\left(\frac{1}{x+1-i\pi}-\frac{1}{x+1+i\pi}\right).$$

P.S. My answer simplified the fraction.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE:$$\frac{10}{x^2+2x+1+\pi^2}=\frac{10}{(x+1)^2+\pi^2}=\\
\frac{a}{x+1+i\pi}+\frac{b}{x+1-i\pi}=\\\frac{a(x+1-i\pi)+b(x+1+i\pi)}{(x+1)^1+\pi^2}=\\
\frac{(x+1)(a+b)-i\pi(a-b)}{(x+1)^1+\pi^2}=\\\to a+b=0 \to a=-b\\
and \\(-i\pi)(a-b)=10\to a-b=\frac{10}{-i\pi}$$so $$-2b=\frac{10}{-i\pi}\to b=\frac{5}{i\pi}=\frac{5}{i\pi}\frac ii=-\frac{5i}{\pi}\\a=\frac{5i}{\pi}$$

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember than you can always process by identification of the coefficients as a fallback when you don't see some other shortcut.

$\dfrac{10}{x^2+2x+1+\pi^2}=\dfrac{a}{x-1+i\pi}+\dfrac{b}{x-1-i\pi}=\dfrac{x(a+b)-(a+b+ai\pi-bi\pi)}{x^2+2x+1+\pi^2}$

Therefore you get to solve

$\begin{cases}a+b=0\\(a+b)+(a-b)i\pi=-10\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}b=-a\\2ai\pi=-10\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}a=\frac {5i}{\pi}\\b=-\frac{5i}{\pi}\end{cases}$

Comment: thank you so much :)